# Why isn't this returning unique combinations of these attributes?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

When using the following query:

```
with neededSkills(SkillCode) as (
    select distinct SkillCode
    from job natural join hasprofile natural join requires_skill
    where job_code = '1'
    minus
    select skillcode
    from person natural join hasskill
    where id = '1'
)
select distinct
  taughtin.c_code as c,
  count(taughtin.skillcode) as s,
  ti.c_code as cc,
  count(ti.skillcode) as ss
 from taughtin, taughtin ti
where taughtin.c_code <> ti.c_code
  and taughtin.skillcode <> ti.skillcode
  and taughtin.skillcode in (select skillcode from neededskills)
  and ti.skillcode in (select skillcode from neededskills)
group by (taughtin.c_code, ti.c_code)
order by (taughtin.c_code);
```

It returns:

```
 C  | S  | CC | SS
----|----|----|----
 1  | 1  | 2  | 1
 1  | 1  | 3  | 1
 1  | 1  | 5  | 1
 2  | 1  | 1  | 1
 3  | 1  | 1  | 1
 5  | 1  | 1  | 1
```

I would expect it to return only lines where the combination of `C` and `CC` was not already used. Do  I misunderstand how `group by` works? How would I achieve this result?

I am trying to have it return:

```
 C  | S  | CC | SS
----|----|----|----
 1  | 1  | 2  | 1
 1  | 1  | 3  | 1
 1  | 1  | 5  | 1
```

I use `Oracle SQLPlus`.

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results would be quite helpful.

Comment: Add `AND TAUGHTIN.C_CODE = 1` to the end of the `WHERE` clause. Best of luck.

Comment: You're misunderstanding, but I'm not sure why you thing you'd only get half the results. Getting your result from that data is easy enough but without knowing your logic it isn't ncessarily correct for your real situation.

Comment: @AlexPoole Im trying to get only one combination of c and cc. It doesn't matter whether 1 in c or cc so long as it is combined with 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping on the combination of `taughtin.c_code` and `ti.c_code`, which are seperate columns in the context of the query (even though they are the same column in the schema). A pair of `1, 2` is not the same as a pair of `2, 1`; the values may be the same but the sources are not.

If you want to get the combinations one way but not the other then the simplest thing is to always make one value large than the other; instead of:

```
where taughtin.c_code <> ti.c_code
```

use:

```
where ti.c_code > taughtin.c_code
```

Though it would be better to use ANSI joins for the main query too, and I'm not a fan of natural joins. You also don't need either `distinct`; the first may eliminate duplicates but they don't logically matter if you're only using the temporary result set for `in()`